# Why extrapolating a linear model breaks the regression line

Tags: regression, predictive-models

When extrapolating a regression line a bit further from the observed range of predictors, I get values way over what seems expected from the fitted model. If the intercept and the slope create a line that should go through the original dataset, I wonder why the predicted new values do not just lay close to an extension of the original line. Here is the dataset:

```
d=data.frame(
y=c(27.0, 27.2, 25.3, 25.1 ,26.1 ,30.0, 26.2, 29.0 ,26.0, 29.7, 25.9),
x1=c(1.20,1.24,0.86,0.07,0.38,0.62,0.20,0.69,0.50,0.89,0.60),
x2=c(21.0,21.0,21.0,23.8,23.8,23.8,23.8,23.5,23.5,23.5,23.5))
```

Here is the model:

```
 m=lm(y~x1+x2,data=d)
```

Here is the new data range to extrapolate:

```
nd=data.frame(
x1=c(1.50, 1.30, 0.78, 1.00),
x2=c(25.6,26.7,26.3,28.2))
nd$y <- predict(m, nd)
```

Now I put them together to plot them:

```
d$group=rep("old",11)
nd$group=rep("newdata",4)
s=rbind(d,nd)
```

Now I plot them:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(s, aes(x=x1, y=y, group=group)) +
geom_point(aes(colour=factor(group), 
             fill = factor(group)), 
         shape=21, size = 2)+
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

This seems a very bad extrapolation...

Comment: I'm not that convinced your question is actually about programming or should have been closed for that, but it hints at a lack of understanding what your linear model is doing. I suggest you also have a look how far outside the observed domain your new data is in the `x2` dimension, and particularly the combination of both. Your model is $y=-18.450+6.464x_1+1.799x_2$ which results in a predicted value of about $38.75$ for the point $x_1=1, x_2=28.2$ which matches your plot exactly.

Comment: Thank you pbulls. I see that, but should not extrapolation be consistent in the two dimensions of the model?  with that I mean, simply extend the line for both x1 and x2?

Comment: When I take logs, the predicted values look far much closer to what I'd expect (30-31), but this is also intriguing... Also, the regression line remains broken in ggplot2... so there seem to be two problems here: one associated to how the predict function integrates predictors in different scales and another associated to how ggplot plots a multivariate regression line. I have looked up in two AI assistants and the internet and cannot find a satisfactory solution yet..

Comment: The problem with your `ggplot` code is that you are explicitly asking for a **different** linear model in only one dimension (separately for old and new data even!), so that is never going to match the results from the first model. And no, your predictions condition jointly on `x1` and `x2` so it doesn't make a lot of sense to expect this to match "extending the line for `x1`". That line is actually a *plane*.

Comment: I still think it does make sense to expect the line to extend to the observations. Yes, a model conditioned on two dimensions creates a plane, but that is still a straight plane. It seems to me the problem here was threefold: 1) for some reason still not well understood, taking logs on the components was important to lead to more reasonable predictions (lower values).  2) use the variable group in AES. In that way, ggplot2 is creating a separate fitting line for each data group, and 3) thinking ggplot2 would use the two predictors to fit the line.

Comment: @PBulls It seems to me that your comments make up an answer.  Could you post it as one?

Comment: I was unable to since the question had been closed, but I can write it up for sure.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, there is nothing 'wrong' with these predictions, other than that extrapolating from a multiple linear regression is possibly even more questionable than doing so in one dimension.

Your actual model fit is $y=−18.450+6.464x_1+1.799x_2$. Plugging in the values of your prediction points gets you the following $y$ values (from small to large): $33.89$, $37.29$, $37.97$, and $38.73$. These are pretty much exactly the values seen in your plot.

The reason they are much higher than for the other $x_1$ values is that your new points not only lie on the edge of the fitted $x_1$ dimension, they are really quite far outside the observed $x_2$ range (which you are not plotting). The combination of these two produces $y$ values that are also outside the previously observed range. I've tried to plot this in 3D (always a fun exercise) with the fitted points in black, the predicted ones in red, and the observed range of the regression line overplotted:
[image: 3D scatter plot of regression]

As you can see the new predictions aren't *that* surprising if you take into account all dimensions of the problem.

Another issue with your `ggplot` code is that you request a *new* regression in that plot instead of the original one, fitting $y$ onto $x_1$ only. This further buries the lede: it was $x_2$ that was driving most of the apparent increase in $y$, and for any given $x_1$ you can predict **all** values of $y$ depending on $x_2$. Consider $x_1=1$, then $6.66\le x_2\le62.3$ gets you the entire line $y=[0,100]$ from your original model. It is simply meaningless to consider only one parameter when interpreting a prediction from this multiple regression.